# Android и удалённая БД. Нужны советы

Tags: android, mysql, база-данных

Появилась необходимость через приложение андроид получать доступ у удалённой БД и производить действия. Действия стандартные: добавление, поиск и т.п. Так вот подскажите, что для этого необходимо? Пошастал по инету и вырисовалась такая картина: Нужна сама БД и веб-сервер. Т.к напрямую к БД коннектится не дает. Мне необходимо получать и отправлять json cтроки. Почитал в инете и получается что на серваке должны лежать уже готовые php файлы, которые и будут формировать сами запросы. Это нормально? Т.е не получится сразу отправить SQL запрос и получить json? В общем прощу совета как и с чего начать? Так же благодарен буду за ссылки по данной теме. В общем как правильно организовать передачу\приём json? Как эта передача происходить должна? Строкой, файлом?  Извините если вопросы туповатые, но с чего-то начинать надо.

Comment: MySQL, начиная с 5.7.8, знает о существовании JSON и даже умеет с ними работать, см. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html. _Т.к напрямую к БД коннектится не дает._ - пардон, кто именно не даёт?

Comment: Напрямую с андроида к MySQL не коннектится.

Comment: Android cannot connect directly to the database server. Therefore we need to create a simple web service that will pass the requests to the database and will return the response.

Comment: А в качестве веб-сервера что использовать удобнее? И как передавать\принимать json правильно?  Неужели надо хранить скрипты и к ним обращаться через get\post?

Comment: @Kamenev_D , видимо ты ни разу не сталкивался с клиент-серверным приложением. Но да, нужен сервер, на котором будут серверные приложения (скрипты php, либо что-то на Java, C# или вообще много на чем), к которым нужно обращаться запросами (get,post и т.д), которые будут отвечать JSON строками.

Comment: Не сталкивался, поэтому и прошу советов. Nikotin N, а либо что-то на Java, можно подробнее? Можно веб-сервер на Яве поднять?

Comment: Если загуглить "веб сервер на java" , то первая ссылка думаю сразу подойдет - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732109/simple-http-server-in-java-using-only-java-se-api

Comment: Ага, пишем веб-сервер, прикручиваем его к  БД. При получении запроса от клиента, делаем выборку и отправляем обратно. Правильно? Ещё вопрос: Как лучше передовать json? Точнее как правильно? Тупо строку или упаковывать и отправлять? Если запрос длинный может есть смысл в архив паковать и передавать?

Comment: Вроде того. На сколько я знаю передается строка. А вот что упаковать?